# Assign numeric order to each grouped variable subset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
var<-c("df1::x2","df1::x2","df1::x2","df1::x6","df1::6","df1::x7","df1::x7","df1::x7")
mValue<-c("3months","6months","12months","yes","no", "male","female","i dont't know")
valueOrder<-"NA"
dat<-data.frame(var, mValue, valueOrder)
```

Now what I want to do is to assign numeric order within each grouped vars (x2, x6 and x7), ideally, it should look like this:

```
var             mValue         valueOrder
df1::x2         3months             1
df1::x2         6months             2
df1::x2         12months            3
df1::x6         yes                 1
df1::x6         no                  2
df1::x7         male                1
df1::x7         female              2
df1::x7         i don't know        3
```

I am not sure whether I need to use group_by to group "var" first, and then use some functions to assign numeric order, or there is smarter and more efficient way to handle that. Could Someone help to tell how I can achieve this outcome? Thanks a lot~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `rowid` - remove the prefix part of the 'var' column using `trimws` till the `::` and use `rowid` (from `data.table` to get the sequence)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(valueOrder = rowid(trimws(var, whitespace = ".*::")))
```

-output

```
dat
       var        mValue valueOrder
1 df1::x2       3months          1
2 df1::x2       6months          2
3 df1::x2      12months          3
4 df1::x6           yes          1
5 df1::x6            no          2
6 df1::x7          male          1
7 df1::x7        female          2
8 df1::x7 i dont't know          3
```

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun. It is my bad to input incorrect var's name. It worked perfectly now~~! One more following question for that: now for some vars, eg: df1::x101, it has 3 values (yes, no and  I dont know), how can I change their defaulted order (now is like i dont know =1, yes=2, no=3 in valueOrder col) to customized order (like I want to yes =1 in valueOrder col, no=2, and "i dont know"=3)? Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: @Rstudyer If this is only for certain 'var' cases, I would create a keyval data and join i.e. `keydat <- tibble(mValue = c("yes", "no", "i don't know"), tmp = 1:3); dat %>%
    mutate(valueOrder = rowid(trimws(var, whitespace = ".*::"))) %>% left_join(keydat) %>% mutate(valueOrder = coalesce(tmp, valueOrder), .keep = "unused")`

Comment: Thanks so much~~~@akrun! If I have multiple rules like that. eg (other than yes, no and i don't know, i have another customized one: checked=1, unchecked =2), so I need to repeat the code as you wrote above, which create keydat2<-tibble(mValue=c("checked","unchecked", tmp=1:2); ...and do the left join again, right? or I can merge this rule to keydat and avoid repeated code (keydat2)?

Comment: @Rstudyer you can have all of them in a single keydat  with mValue and tmp as columns and do the join once, and `coalesce` so that it will replace only if there is value in 'keydat'

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave` to cumulative count duplicates of `var` by `var` group.

```
transform(dat, valueOrder=ave(var, var, FUN=\(x) cumsum(duplicated(x)) + 1))
#       var        mValue valueOrder
# 1 df1::x2       3months          1
# 2 df1::x2       6months          2
# 3 df1::x2      12months          3
# 4 df1::x6           yes          1
# 5 df1::x6            no          2
# 6 df1::x7          male          1
# 7 df1::x7        female          2
# 8 df1::x7 i dont't know          3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(var = c("df1::x2", "df1::x2", "df1::x2", "df1::x6", 
"df1::x6", "df1::x7", "df1::x7", "df1::x7"), mValue = c("3months", 
"6months", "12months", "yes", "no", "male", "female", "i dont't know"
), valueOrder = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```